# Where is the source code for chrome devtools implementation for Android Webview?

Tags: android, webview, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to find the implementation of Android webview. On Android's source code, I have only been able to find abstract classes/wrappers/proxy classes (on cs.android.com).

Specifically, I want to understand how chrome devtools protocol is implemented by the webview. How does the webview use this flag:
`WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);`?

Comment: Use https://cs.android.com/

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned I found wrapper/proxy classes, but not the actual implementation. It looks like is loading some native library which may not be there in Android source code?

Comment: AFAICT, the android-non-updatable.stubs file is processed by some build script. Find it and analyze.

Comment: Any luck with this? I am on the same quest.